# tomcat crossdomain.xml not found 404

Tags: tomcat, crossdomain.xml

I'm running a web server that requires crossdomain.xml at the root of the tomcat server

The current `Tomcat` folder configuration:

```
webapps/
    ROOT/crossdomain.xml
    web/server_files port 8080
```

Under `web` folder there is a file `clientapp.jsp` that start flash application

1. `ipAddress:8080/crossdomain.xml` results in 404 - Web server bound to port 8080 and ROOT is not running - at least not on port 8080
2. Call to `ipadress:8080/web/clientapp` results in `ipadress:8080/crossdomain.xml` not found 404

*My Question*

If the Root Context of my web server is **web** (http:localhost:8080/web), How can i redirect/ catch /run url such as:

`http:localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml`

Comment: I wouldn't expect a request to `ipaddress:8080/crossdomain.xml` to return a 404. You'll need to fix that, first. The information stated in your question is confusing, especially under point #1. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Thanks for your response. Edited. Sorry for the confusion